# How to repeat a spin?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Well, this is my code it works well, that's how I want it, but this is just 50% of what I want.

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44%;
  left: 21%;
  width: 82px;
  height: 82px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 4s linear repeat;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 4s;
  animation: spin 0.4s linear 2;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" />
```

And when it does its spin, I want it to wait for 4 seconds and then repeat the code many times.
I don't want to change the `animation:spin 0.4s linear 2` the image should spin 2 times in 0.4s without any delay after the first spin. If there is a better code then why not changing it :D

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I changed keyframes a bit to adjust your requirements. I also added `infinite` to run animation continuously.

PS: I removed `--webkit-`, `--moz-` for simplicity, for maximum compilability you can translate `animation` and `keyframes` for different browsers.

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44%;
  left: 21%;
  width: 82px;
  height: 82px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  16% {
    transform: rotate(720deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(720deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" />
```

I set animation duration to 5 seconds. During first 0.8 seconds (=5s*0.16) image spins 720 degrees (spinning 2 times around its center). Then waits for 4.2 seconds (If you need to wait exactly 4 seconds, you'll need to do a quick math to adjust numbers a bit).